# Remove the extra space in block element

Tags: html, css

I prefer providing the actual code makes sense to this question. I have the following working code.

```css
.vc-section-heading {
  text-align: left;
}

.vc-section-heading-sup-txt {
  display: block;
  color: #b18d56;
}

.vc-section-heading h1 {
  padding-top: 0;
  padding-left: 30px;
  padding-right: 30px;
  color: #1a2431;
  font-size: 34px;
}

.vc-section-heading h1 {
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  font-size: 34px;
}

.vc-section-heading h1:after,
.vc-section-heading h1:before {
  position: absolute;
  width: auto;
  bottom: auto;
  left: auto;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-65%) !important;
  -moz-transform: translateY(-65%) !important;
  -ms-transform: translateY(-65%) !important;
  -o-transform: translateY(-65%) !important;
  transform: translateY(-65%) !important;
  color: #b18d56;
}

.vc-section-heading h1:before {
  content: '[';
  left: 0 !important;
  right: auto !important;
}

.vc-section-heading h1:after {
  content: ']';
  right: 0 !important;
  left: auto !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="vc-section-heading">
  <span class="vc-section-heading-sup-txt">Welcome To Our Industry</span>
  <h1 style="text-transform: none;/* display: inline; */">We Have 25 Years Of Experience</h1>
</div>
```

Here I am facing a problem in responsive design. When it comes to iPad or lesser devices the content of `h1` is breaking into the next line, but the `h1:after` doesn't fit the width. It stays in the corner and providing an unexpected space.

To make it more clear I set the `body width` to `500px` here.

```css
BODY {
  WIDTH: 500PX;
}

.vc-section-heading {
  text-align: left;
}

.vc-section-heading-sup-txt {
  display: block;
  color: #b18d56;
}

.vc-section-heading h1 {
  padding-top: 0;
  padding-left: 30px;
  padding-right: 30px;
  color: #1a2431;
  font-size: 34px;
}

.vc-section-heading h1 {
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  font-size: 34px;
}

.vc-section-heading h1:after,
.vc-section-heading h1:before {
  position: absolute;
  width: auto;
  bottom: auto;
  left: auto;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-65%) !important;
  -moz-transform: translateY(-65%) !important;
  -ms-transform: translateY(-65%) !important;
  -o-transform: translateY(-65%) !important;
  transform: translateY(-65%) !important;
  color: #b18d56;
}

.vc-section-heading h1:before {
  content: '[';
  left: 0 !important;
  right: auto !important;
}

.vc-section-heading h1:after {
  content: ']';
  right: 0 !important;
  left: auto !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="vc-section-heading">
  <span class="vc-section-heading-sup-txt">Welcome To Our Industry</span>
  <h1 style="text-transform: none;/* display: inline; */">We Have 25 Years Of Experience</h1>
</div>
```

As you can see here, the text `Experience` is went to the next line and `]` is staying in the end with a space with the content. How can remove this unwanted space?

**The output I am currently getting is,**

[image]

**The output I am looking for is,**

[image]

Comment: Whats about font-size: 30px; ?

Comment: @jaydeeppatel it's the design. Nothing to do with it sir

Comment: `.vc-section-heading h1 {width:100%}` like this?

Comment: @Roy I tried it. But it gave no changes. Actually I tried inline, inline-block  and some stuffs with width. Since the value of the h1 and span are dynamic, I can go for a pixel value

Comment: @Ramesh But, what do you need? down the **]** or up _experience_?

Comment: @Roy actually the `]` has to come after the `h1` where it's content ends relative to the width. `width:fit-content` even not supporting to my problem

Comment: what if you remove the position absolute from beforeand after

Comment: @godfather please check the updated question

Comment: @Ramesh Check my updated answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the js solution.

https://jsfiddle.net/moorthyrweb/hgfs9kb3/3/

Modified html

```
<h1>
   <span>We Have 25 Years Of Experience</span>
</h1>
```

javascript

```
function fitWidth(el) {
    el.style.width = '';
  // Add 1 to fix floating point error correction
  el.style.width = `${el.children[0].offsetWidth + 1}px`;
  el.style.display = '';
}

const element = document.querySelector('h1');
fitWidth(element);

// If body width is not fixed, you can call it in resize event
window.addEventListener('resize', function() {
    fitWidth(element);
})
```

Comment: Thank you for your time on this question sir. In your answer, the `]` ends with the line. Instead, I want the bracket to end with the entire content and vertically centre aligned.

Comment: Would you like a javascript solution?

Comment: Not an issue. Go ahead

Comment: Modified the answer for js solution

Comment: Did you made any css changes?

Comment: No CSS changes required

Answer (score 1):

I have added margin to the heading (instead of padding), this then allows you to move the `:before` and `:after` into the margin with `-20px`.

```css
@media screen and (max-width:767px) {
  .vc-section-heading h1 {
    max-width: 320px;
  }
}

.vc-section-heading-sup-txt {
  display: block;
  color: #b18d56;
}

.vc-section-heading h1 {
  margin: 0 20px;
  color: #1a2431;
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  font-size: 34px;
}

.vc-section-heading h1:after,
.vc-section-heading h1:before {
  position: absolute;
  width: auto;
  bottom: auto;
  left: auto;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-65%) !important;
  color: #b18d56;
}

.vc-section-heading h1:before {
  content: '[';
  left: -20px;
}

.vc-section-heading h1:after {
  content: ']';
  right: -20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="vc-section-heading">
  <span class="vc-section-heading-sup-txt">Welcome To Our Industry</span>
  <h1>We Have 25 Years Of Experience</h1>
</div>
```

You can see this working with different lengths of text here:

```css
@media screen and (max-width:797px) {
  .vc-section-heading {
    max-width: 320px;
  }
}

.vc-section-heading-sup-txt {
  display: block;
  color: #b18d56;
}

.vc-section-heading h1 {
  margin: 0 20px;
  color: #1a2431;
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  font-size: 34px;
}

.vc-section-heading h1:after,
.vc-section-heading h1:before {
  position: absolute;
  width: auto;
  bottom: auto;
  left: auto;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-65%) !important;
  color: #b18d56;
}

.vc-section-heading h1:before {
  content: '[';
  left: -20px;
}

.vc-section-heading h1:after {
  content: ']';
  right: -20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="vc-section-heading">
  <span class="vc-section-heading-sup-txt">Welcome To Our Industry</span>
  <h1>We Have 25 Years</h1>
</div>

<div class="vc-section-heading">
  <span class="vc-section-heading-sup-txt">Welcome To Our Industry</span>
  <h1>We Have 25 Years Of Experience this text string is a lot longer</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: This has to be the output. But the content goes beyond the parent element's width. Set body `width:500px`, still the inner content is out of the body width.

Comment: @Ramesh I see what you mean! You could add in a media query so that the max-width is set for smaller devices which makes it stack? I have updated my answer above - you can view the different with full screen :-)

Comment: Contents are dynamic as I mentioned in the comment section. When the content is smaller, it won't need the media query as well as the query depends on the content. Lets say a sentence like "Hello I am here to say that I am not well prepared", All the words in the above sentence have very few letters. So it makes major changes in multiple divice break points

Comment: @Ramesh. Yes i can see that this string works too - have you tried the code above? The brackets are set to be at the end of the block, no matter how many words are there. With the media query, you are just making sure that the block doesn't overflow on smaller devices :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `text-align: justify;` to `h1` to fill all the space.

```
.vc-section-heading h1 {
  text-align: justify;
}
```

Comment: It's adding more spaces between the words.